# How to create a function in bashrc to accept arguments?

Tags: function, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, bash

I would like to have an alias in my bashrc file to append the argument passed to it from terminal. For example:

```
$ lh300
```

calls:

```
alias lh3000='open http://localhost:3000'
```

However, if I type:

$ lh8080
or lh followed by any number:

```
$ lh####
```

I would like to call a function that appends the #### into an alias that will

```
'open http://localhost:####'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Should this question be placed in the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You won't be able to use an alias, but you can create a function:

```
lh() { open http://localhost:$1; }
```

Then just call it like `lh 3000`.

Answer (score 3):

A questionable hack involving `command_not_found_handle`:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
    if [[ $1 =~ lh([[:digit:]]+) ]]; then
        open "http://localhost:$BASH_REMATCH[1]"
    fi
}
```

This requires `bash` 4 or later, I believe.